# Spring xml file referencing service issue

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a problem with spring service import problem through xml files.

A.xml

```
<bean id="AtomService" class="{class}">
    <property name="sqlSession" ref="sqlSession"/>
</bean>
```

B.xml

```
<bean id="BtomService" class="{class}">
    <property name="AtomService" ref="AtomService"/>
</bean>
```

I have tried to put import syntax in B.xml file like (path was accurate)

```
<import resource:~~A.xml>
```

and to configure Beans support(config Sets) tab on STS. but they were not helpful.
Error occurs log is not about beans but make nullPointerException for variables referenced.
If you have any solutions please let me know..

Comment: what is sqlSession?

Comment: I have no clue on what your actual question is?What is the problem you are trying to solve? The `import` statement you show isn't even valid.

Comment: @M.Deinum 
My question was AtomService in B.xml is not referenced..
import syntax I have tried is below
<import resource="classpath:spring-config.xml" />

Comment: Again it still isn't clear what problem you are trying to solve. Doesn't your application start? Do you get an exception? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and refine your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum application starts properly but there is exception and AtomService is not working

Comment: @Jaiwo99 That is nothing you can ignore that

Comment: If it starts the import is working else your application won't start. Hence your error lies somewhere else.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yeah but injection is not working only for AtomService

Comment: I doubt that it isn't working. I guess you are doing a `new AtomService` or something in your code instead of using the actual Spring managed instance.